# Gradle hangs on transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I run `gradle 3.0.0-alpha7` from console, I do not use any IDE. When I execute `gradle build` the execution hangs on the transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease stage.

I tried to clean and build, then build and clean, remove the .gradle directory and even cleaned my monitor but nothing helped.

Here is the log from Gradle:

```
11:56:27.745 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre7/1.1.3-2/3fe54c7558c903868351ac79b792d152bca958f2/kotlin-stdlib-jre7-1.1.3-2.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@4cd665df
11:56:27.745 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-v4-25.3.0.aar/223f022110b9597341bd8d9a7328e8e3/jars/classes.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@4c116f36
11:56:27.746 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/work/ros/android/XXX_XXX2_Android/XXX_XXX2_Android_Compute_Shaders/XXX_XXX2_Android/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/release : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@543aad5e
11:56:27.746 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/work/arsdk/XXXXXX/thirdpartyrepos/ModernGLDemos/java6-android-glframework/java6-glutils-commons/build/libs/java6-glutils-commons.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@432d44dd
11:56:27.746 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton/butterknife/6.1.0/63735f48b82bcd24cdd33821342428252eb1ca5a/butterknife-6.1.0.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@7ef1282
11:56:27.746 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-media-compat-25.3.0.aar/aa72d1100d9548481314c6d5489399ee/jars/classes.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@3dc1fb75
11:56:27.746 [INFO] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexTransform] Adding PreDexCallable for /home/alexander/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-core-ui-25.3.0.aar/273754783abeeddf4d000035c32cff14/jars/classes.jar : com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable@3477775a
11:56:33.853 [null] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] 
11:56:33.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24533991424}
11:56:33.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24533991424}
11:56:33.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 3817865216, Committed: 957874176}
11:56:38.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24540717056}
11:56:38.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24540717056}
11:56:38.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 3817865216, Committed: 957874176}
11:56:41.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
11:56:41.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:41.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:41.309 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:41.310 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:41.310 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:41.310 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
11:56:43.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24559333376}
11:56:43.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24559333376}
11:56:43.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 3817865216, Committed: 957874176}
11:56:48.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24571006976}
11:56:48.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 33674444800, Free: 24571006976}
11:56:48.853 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 3817865216, Committed: 957874176}
```

The last lines repeat for eternity and the build does not progress.

It seems like four worker threads are locked here:

```
"ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3" #33 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff404a15800 nid=0x5b4a runnable [0x00007ff3e9df9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.lock(FileDispatcherImpl.java:90)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1072)
    at com.android.ide.common.util.ReadWriteProcessLock.acquireFileLock(ReadWriteProcessLock.java:301)
    at com.android.ide.common.util.ReadWriteProcessLock.acquireReadLock(ReadWriteProcessLock.java:220)
    - locked <0x0000000787935680> (a java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger)
    at com.android.ide.common.util.ReadWriteProcessLock.access$200(ReadWriteProcessLock.java:82)
    at com.android.ide.common.util.ReadWriteProcessLock$ReadLock.lock(ReadWriteProcessLock.java:344)
    at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:260)
    at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.read(SynchronizedFile.java:215)
    at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.lambda$queryCacheEntry$6(FileCache.java:398)
    at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache$$Lambda$316/1238620255.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:265)
    at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.read(SynchronizedFile.java:215)
    at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.queryCacheEntry(FileCache.java:391)
    at com.android.builder.utils.FileCache.createFile(FileCache.java:273)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable.call(PreDexCallable.java:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.PreDexCallable.call(PreDexCallable.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

What could be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in the Android Gradle plugin. It seems that several threads are in dead lock state while trying to lock some files.

`--max-workers 1` helped to workaround the problem.

But in general if you face similar problem try to dump threads and see what they are doing. `jvisualvm` is one of the tools that can help doing it.